# Proving equivalence of statements without using a truth table

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

How can I prove these statements without using a truth table?

$1.\quad (p \leftrightarrow q) \equiv (p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q)$

$2. \quad (p \land q \land r) \equiv \neg p \lor \neg q \lor \neg r$

$3.\quad p \land (p \lor r) \equiv p$

Comment: You're looking for the symbol ⇔. Also, please use LaTeX.

Comment: @DHMO Actually, he _is_ using LaTeX (or at least MathJax), but only on single symbols, not whole expressions.

Comment: @Arthur I only saw that after I clicked edit, so whatever.

Comment: Work with that on your own. If you were to narrow/edit your question post so that, indeed, only one question is asked, perhaps you'll get more help,

Comment: @DHMO You're right, of course.

Comment: If you are trying to solve it as a MCQ rather than proving then I would suggest rewrite them as digital logic symbols (if you have already covered that) and solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted three separate questions in one question field.

So I will not answer them all.  I will give hints for each:

$(1)\;$ Note that by definition, 
$$\begin{align} p\leftrightarrow q &\equiv (p\to q) \land (q \to p)\tag{Definition of biconditional}\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p)\tag{implication}
\end{align}$$

Use the distributive property (a couple of times, if needed) we can work to show it is  equivalent to  $$(p\land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$$   I'll let you take it from here.

---

$(2)\;$ Use DeMorgan's twice (and make use of the associative property), on $\neg (p \land q \land r),\,$ to show that is equivalent to  $\;\neg p \lor \neg q \lor \neg r.$

$$\begin{align}
\neg (p \land q \land r)
&\equiv \lnot ((p\land q) \land r)\tag{associativity}\\ \\ 
&\equiv (\lnot (p\land q) \lor \lnot r) \tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\ 
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\lor \lnot r \tag{DeMorgan's again}\\ \\
&\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot r\tag{associativity}
\end{align}$$

---

$(3)\;$ use the distributive property  on $\;p \land (p \lor r)\;$ to show it is equivalent to $\;p.$ 
$$\begin{align} 
p \land (p \lor r)&\equiv (p\land p) \lor (p \land r)\tag{distributive property}\\ \\  &\equiv p \lor (p\land r) \tag{Why is $p\land p \equiv p$?}
\end{align}$$

I'll let you finish the proof for $(3)$.

Comment: HJY: If you'd like me to check your work upon your completion of the proofs of $(1), (3),\,$ feel free to post your work, and I'll be happy to review it.